# Proving $\textrm{im}\ T^n=\textrm{im}\ T^{n+1}$ without the rank-nullity theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to work out the the proof of the following proposition, which came up in the context of Jordan canonical form of a linear operator.

**Proposition.** Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional $\mathbb K$-vetor space and let $T: V\rightarrow V$ be a linear operator. Then:

$a)$ $\textrm{ker}\ T^n=\textrm{ker}\ T^{n+1}$;

$b)$ $\textrm{im}\ T^n=\textrm{im}\ T^{n+1}$.

How to prove it?

**Remark 1)** Notice that

$$\{0\}=\textrm{ker}\ T^0\subset \textrm{ker}\ T\subset \textrm{ker}\ T^2\subset \cdots \subset \textrm{ker}\ T^n\subset \textrm{ker}\ T^{n+1}\subset \cdots$$

and

$$V=\textrm{im}\ T^0\supset \textrm{im}\ T \supset \cdots \supset \textrm{im}\ T^n\supset \textrm{im}\ T^{n+1}\supset \cdots.$$

The inclusions are not assumed to be strict.

**Remark 2.** By induction it follows that:

$i)$ If $\textrm{ker}\ T^{k}=\textrm{ker}\ T^{k+1}$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, then $\textrm{ker}\ T^{k}=\textrm{ker}\ T^l$ for every $l\geq k$;

$ii)$ If $\textrm{im}\ T^k=\textrm{im}\ T^{k+1}$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, then $\textrm{im}\ T^k=\textrm{im}\ T^l$ for every $l\geq k$.

**Remark 3.** Notice $b)$ follows from $a)$ using the rank nullity theorem:

\begin{align*} 
\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{im}\ T^{n+1}&=\textrm{dim}\ V-\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T^{n+1}\\
&=\textrm{dim}\ V-\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T^{n}\\
&=\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{im}\ T^n.
\end{align*}
However, I'd like a proof to $b)$ which does not rely on the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: I don't follow why $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker} T^n \ge n$ in (II)

Comment: I like to show that when two images/kernel are equal, then they are equal for all larger powers.  Then use a dimension argument to show that the image/kernel can shrink/grow only $n$ times.

Comment: @Youem $\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T^n\geq \textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T^{n-1}+1$, since $\textrm{ker}\ T^{n-1}\subset \textrm{ker}\ T^n$. Now repeat this argument up to $\textrm{ker}\ T^{n-n}+n=n$.

Comment: Why the kernels are strictly increasing?

Comment: @Youem Right! I haven't assured that..

Comment: @MichaelBurr I have already shown that when two images/kernel are equal, then they are equal for all larger powers. Is it always true that $\textrm{ker}\ T^n=V$ and $\textrm{im}\ T^n=\{0\}$?

Comment: @PtF No it is not always true at all. For example $T=0$ or $T=I$

Comment: @Youem $\ker T$ is increases as power of $T$ increases. And if $\ker T^m= \ker T^{m+1}$  for some $m$ ,then $\ker(T^k) =\ker (T^m) $ for all $k\ge m$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: To prove the statement correctly let $p=\min\{k: ker T^k = ker T^{k+1}\}$. Prove that for all $m\ge p$, $ker T^{m} = ker T^{m+1}$.

Now finally use the increasing argument to show that $p\le n$. Same thing can be done to $im$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the hints I came up with the correct proof:

$a)$ If $\textrm{ker}\ T^k\neq \textrm{ker}\ T^{k+1}$ for every $k\in \mathbb N$, then

$$\textrm{dim}\ T^k\geq k$$

for every $k\in \mathbb N$. This would imply

$$\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T^{n+1}\geq n+1>n$$

which is impossible, since $\textrm{dim}\ V=n$ and $\textrm{ker}\ T^{n+1}$ is a subspace of $V$. This shows that the set of non-negative integers
$$\{k\in\mathbb N: \textrm{ker}\ T^k=\textrm{ker}\ T^{k+1}\}$$
is non-empty. By the well ordering of $\mathbb N$ there is the **least** integer $p$ such that $p\geq 0$ and

$$\textrm{ker}\ T^p=\textrm{ker}\ T^{p+1}.$$

In particular,

$$\{0\}\subsetneq \textrm{ker}\ T\subsetneq \textrm{ker}\ T^2\subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq \textrm{ker}\ T^p=\textrm{ker}\ T^{p+1}.$$

But then

\begin{align*} 
&\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T-\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T^0\geq 1\\
&\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T^2-\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T\geq 1\\
&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\vdots\\
&\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T^{p}-\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T^{p-1}\geq 1
\end{align*}
Now adding everything and telescoping,

$$\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T^p=\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T^p-\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T^0\geq p.$$

If it were $p>n$, we would contradict $\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{ker}\ T^p\leq n$. So that, $p\leq n$.

But since $\textrm{ker}\ T^p=\textrm{ker}\ T^{p+1}$ it follows $\textrm{ker}\ T^p=\textrm{ker}\ T^{l}$ for every $l\geq p$. In particular, $\textrm{ker}\ T^n=\textrm{ker}\ T^{n+1}$.

An analogous argument applies to $\textrm{im}\ T^n$.

Comment: Good! But how did you prove the last statement that for $l\ge p$, $ker T^l = ker T^p$?

Comment: Using induction. I didn't include for the answer would be too long..

Comment: @PtF in that case your argument seems to me correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof without Rank-Nullity theorem:**

> Theorem $1$: Suppose $T\in\mathcal{L}(V) $.Then $V=\textrm{im}\ T^0\supset
>  \textrm{im}\ T\supset \cdots \supset \textrm{im}\ T^n\supset
> \textrm{im}\ T^{n+1}\supset \cdots$

> Theorem $2$: Suppose $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$.Suppose $\exists m\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $\textrm{im} T^m=\textrm{im} T^{m+1}$.Then $\textrm{im} T^m=\textrm{im}T^k$ for all $k\ge m$

$\boxed{\text{Theorem $3$: Suppose $\dim V=n$ then $\textrm{im}\ T^n=\textrm{im}\ T^{n+1}$}}$

Proof:
Assume the contrary
$\textrm{im}\ T^n\neq \textrm{im}\ T^{n+1}$.

Then from Theorem $1$ and Theorem $2$,we have a strictly decreasing sequence

$V=\textrm{im}\ T^0\supsetneq \textrm{im}\ T\supsetneq \cdots \supsetneq \textrm{im}\ T^n\supsetneq \textrm{im}\ T^{n+1}\supsetneq \cdots$

Hence at each of the
strict inclusions in the chain above, the dimension decreases by at least $1$.

$\dim(\textrm{im} T^0) =\dim V=n$ , $\dim(\textrm{im} T^1) \le n-1$

$$\vdots$$

$\begin{align}\dim(\textrm{im} T^{n+1})&\le n-(n+1)\\&=-1\end{align}$

This is a contradiction.

Hence  $\textrm{im}\ T^n=\textrm{im}\ T^{n+1}$.

Comment: And why they are strictly decreasing?

Comment: This is wrong for example if $T$ is the identity map.

Comment: This is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @SouravGhosh even though the proof still wrong.

Comment: Here is only one result that i haven't prove. If image of two consecutive power of $T$ are equal then images of rest of the powers after that are all equal.

Comment: @SouravGhosh identity gives a counterexample to the decreasing argument.

Comment: @Youem I haven't understood my mistake. Please verify again.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I have added all the necessary details but still I haven't understood my mistake.

Comment: @SouravGhosh it is not a mistake. It is more the proof of Theorem 2.

Comment: @Youem Thanks. I have followed Axler.